# Keep Cassandra running on EC2 after shell timeouts

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, cassandra

I can ssh into my amazon EC2 instance and start Cassandra fine. I'll leave the shell up on my dev machine while I make connections from a server. Later the connection breaks and I'll check the shell-- it has timed out and I suppose has terminated the Cassandra process on its way out.

How I launch cassandra from shell:

```
$  nohup bin/cassandra -f &
```

The EC2 instance will be used for production months down the road so I'd like the Cassandra process to be up after I launch it and not go down.

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: can you share the logs .

Comment: For whatever reason, I have had no more issues with Cassandra ending processes. I can log back into the shell and it is running. The log file in ./log is huge. Are you sure you want to see the logs?

Answer (score 1):

You should run Cassandra the same way you would run any other daemon, from your init system (e.g. Systemd or Upstart). If you install Cassandra from the official .deb or .rpm package, it will install the appropriate config file for your init system.